# Get model from table catalog_product_bundle_selection in Magento

Tags: php, magento

how do i get the collection from the table catalog_product_bundle_selection?
I tried already

- getModel(catalog/product_bundle_selection)
- getModel(bundle/selection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this on my command line, and it did work for me:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('bundle/selection')->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $row){
    echo print_r($row->getData(), true);
}
```

Not sure if you were after something else.

Comment: Thanks. i had it correct already. the logging(Mage::log) destination were altered, so i didnt see any log output. sorry for bothering

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to call

`Mage::getModel('bundle/selection')->getCollection();`

As you can see in the file located in `app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml` the table `catalog_product_bundle_selection` is in the tag `<selection>` and inside `<bundle_resource>` xml tag. You can also check this when opening `app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Selection.php`: in the `_construct()` method, is called the `$this->_init('bundle/selection');` that maps the entity table with this grouped notation